# Keep Azure schema in sync with local db using EF

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using Azure to host my website and db and using a local db for production, and using EF code first migrations. I previously published to Azure and have since added to the schema on my local db, but have not kept track of all the migrations as I had to delete the database and rebuild a couple times.

I am now ready to deploy again but my Azure database and local database have different schemas and I can't update them. I tried to run it when I first published and got an error saying a table was missing. I then deleted and rebuilt my local db and published again with the new migration, but I get an error saying that a table already exists.

Is there a way to either figure out what needs to change and publish that migration or delete the database on azure and start again?

Cheers

Comment: Did you get this sorted Brendan?

Comment: No I didn't. Pretty soon after this I moved away from .NET so it wasn't an issue anymore